# Firefox Extremely Buggy now in Linux Mint Rafaela Cinnamon - How to Solve?

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, cinnamon

In my Linux Mint Rafaela Cinnamon, Firefox has suddenly become terribly annoying and buggy. There are several different bugs. One is that when I am in one Gmail account, and I try opening the other from that page, it doesn't get any farther than loading about:blank. Another is when I try to attach any attachment with a size of just a couple megabytes (in GMail) it fails. Yet another one (though this is inconsistent) is when I try to search google from the URL bar, it loads the google search page, but doesn't give results, and I have to refresh the page again. None of these problems existed before, and I have no clue what I have changed. I have tried refreshing AND reinstalling firefox, and it has done no good. What can I do?

Comment: stop using linux mint.

Comment: By refreshing and reinstalling, you mean you have done that with the firefox provided in Mint's repositories, right? (As opposed to precompiled binaries of the latest or the business-use stable ESR version offered by Mozilla themselves.)

Comment: Yes. I do not know how to do the latter.